# Blynk.Begin(auth, ssid, pass) causing watchdog reset

Tags: esp8266, iot, blynk

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/IoT-Motion-Detector-With-NodeMCU-and-BLYNK/#discuss) and I keep hitting a problem repeatedly. I checked in my code that every time it hits the line `Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);`, the serial monitor shows me that there was a `cause:4, boot mode:(3,6) wdt reset`. I looked it up a little bit and learned that this is a "hardware watchdog reset" but I am not sure why this problem is happening. Please let me know if you guys would like anymore info. Thank you!

here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial    // Comment this out to disable prints and save space
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
char auth[] = "xxx";

/* WiFi credentials */
char ssid[] = "xxx";
char pass[] = "xxx";

/* HC-SR501 Motion Detector */
#define ledPin 7 
#define pirPin 2 // Input for HC-S501
int pirValue; // Place to store read PIR Value

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("here 1");
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("here stop?");
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
  Serial.println("here 2");
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  getPirValue();
  Blynk.run();
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("here 3");
}

/***************************************************
 * Get PIR data
 **************************************************/
void getPirValue(void)
{
  pirValue = digitalRead(pirPin);
  if (pirValue) 
  Serial.println("here 4");
  { 
    Serial.println("==> Motion detected");
    Blynk.notify("===> Motion detected");
    Serial.println("here 5"); 
    delay(10);
  }
  digitalWrite(ledPin, pirValue);
  Serial.println("here 6");
}
```

Serial Monitor:

```
[6485] Connected to WiFi
[6486] IP: xx.x.x.xx
[6486] 
    ___  __          __
   / _ )/ /_ _____  / /__
  / _  / / // / _ \/  '_/
 /____/_/\_, /_//_/_/\_\
        /___/ v0.6.1 on ESP8266

[6492] Connecting to blynk-cloud.com:80
[6584] Ready (ping: 38ms).

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
~ld
here 1  (Serial.println in line 19 of code)
here stop? (Serial.println in line 21 of code)
```

Specs:

- Board: Generic ESP8266 Module
- Upload Speed: 115200
- CPU Frequency: 80MHz
- Flash Frequency: 40MHz
- Flash Mode: DOUT (compatible)
- Flash Size: 512K (no SPIFFS)
- Crystal Frequency: 26MHz
- Reset Method: ck
- Debug Port: Disabled
- Debug Level: None
- IwIP Variant: v2 Lower Memory
- VTables: Flash
- Exceptions: Disabled
- Builtin LED: 2
- Erase Flash: Only Sketch
- Espressif FW: nonos-sdk 2.2.1 (legacy)
- SSL Support: All SSL ciphers (most compatible)

Comment: sorry, now I see the true error. you can't use io 7. it is wired to flash memory. what esp8266 board/module do you have?

Comment: Moving from io 7 to io 6 solved the error for a little bit but when the motion sensor detected motion, it restarted again with the same original error. Could my PIR sensor be causing the problem?

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: Changing the io from 6 to 4 solved the problem. Thank you Juraj!